# Reverse roll up of data in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data that looks like the following:

[image: Capture1]

And I want to convert it something like this:

[image: Capture2]

I would normally use VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP for this scenario but I have multiple users reviewing the same presentation so those options don't work as they only return the first instance and not any of the subsequent instances. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this array formula: can be extended to any number of columns:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF($B$2:$D$4=$F2,ROW($B$2:$D$4)),COLUMNS($A:A))),"")
```

Assuming the original list starts in A1 and the new list in F1.

Must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The idea is that the IF statement builds up a 2d array of TRUEs and FALSEs e.g. for Bob:-

```
TRUE  FALSE FALSE
TRUE  FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If the result is true it takes the corresponding row number from the second part of the IF statement:-

```
2
3
4
```

giving

```
2      FALSE FALSE
3      FALSE FALSE
FALSE  FALSE FALSE
```

The point about using the IF statement is that it gives FALSE when the condition isn't true which is ignored by the SMALL function - if you just multiplied the values together you would get some zeroes and the minimum value in the array would always be zero.

Then all it has to do is choose the smallest, second smallest etc. of these elements using SMALL with columns($A:A) - this starts at 1 and goes to 2,3 etc. as it is pulled across.

The result is used as an index into column A to give the presentation. As the formula is pulled across it gives the next presentation until it errors out and shows an empty cell.

[image]

Comment: Great, this worked perfect for me! Would you mind explaining a little bit about what the formula is actually doing?

Comment: Excellent. I will add an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `countifs()` to do this,

For example you could add a transform cell to `G2`: `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$F2,$A:$A,G$1)+COUNTIFS($C:$C,$F2,$A:$A,G$1)+COUNTIFS($D:$D,$F2,$A:$A,G$1)`

You will need to expand the `+countifs()` for every column that you want, eg you currently have three in your example, so will need three `countifs()`

Results:
[image: image of excel showing countifs()]

Then you will need to transform this is you want it into words:

(assuming "how to use excel in the above table is in cell `G2`

```
=IF(G3=1,G$2,"")
```

Will make this:

[image]

It's not the most scalable solution (if your number of reviewers gets too high, but it does work regardless of the number of reviewer names.

Also the `=IF(G3=1,G$2,"")` could be merged into the over all solution, but it's better to show it apart to show workings.

Answer (score 1):

Using an array formula can do this very easy like in the picture below:

[image]

The formula in G2 is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$6=$F2)+($C$2:$C$6=$F2)+($D$2:$D$6=$F2),ROW($A$2:$A$6)),G$1)),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>!

From there, you can copy it everywhere ;)